# Current changes in MongoDB collection done manually is reflected on localhost but not on deployed version in Vercel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I am using Axios to get data from a collection. If I go to the collection and change/edit some document, then reload the localhost, in UI the change is reflected, but in Vercel hosted application, it doesn't reflect the changes. Then if I do any minor change in code like a space or something and then push in GitHub, the deployment happens and then the hosted one reflects the changes.

The most frustrating fact is that there are two API's in total there, both can GET. One works fine, deployed version also shows changes ASAP, but the other one is causing problem.

I am expecting all the API end points should get updated data from MongoDB. Not only when I push something on GitHub and rebuilds.